# Bills of exchange and purchase return

Tags: accounting

You have purchased goods from your supplier on credit. Your supplier drew the bill and you accepted the bill on the same day. A few days later, you discovered some defective materials. You returned the defective supplies to the supplier. In this context, how do you record the transaction of purchase return and how does it affect your bills payable amount when it is honored on a due date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like that twice, although I used credit card.

There are two ways this can be done:

1. The bill is cancelled, or if using credit card, you get a credit card refund. Then you enter the refund transaction as opposite of the original transaction, at the date you returned the goods.

Example:

```
Purchase:
  Debit: Assets - Fixed Assets - Good 1
  Credit: Liabilities - Credit Card

Refund:
  Debit: Liabilities - Credit Card
  Credit: Assets - Fixed Assets - Good 1
```

2. You get a separate payment. For example, one of my purchases where I returned it had a separate bank account transfer to my bank account. Then I just pay the credit card bill in a normal manner. In this case, the second refund transaction is not the opposite of the original transaction because the money is paid via a different method.

Example:

```
Purchase:
  Debit: Assets - Fixed Assets - Good 2
  Credit: Liabilities - Credit Card

Refund:
  Debit: Assets - Current Assets - Checking Account
  Credit: Assets - Fixed Assets - Good 2

Later, credit card / bill payment: 
  Debit: Liabilities - Credit Card
  Credit: Assets - Current Assets - Checking Account
```